# Как расширить возможности класса с помощью другого класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, архитектура

Не могу получить доступ из одного класса в другой. Знаю, что надо использовать наследование.

есть класс "Man"

```
#ifndef MAN_CPP
#define MAN_CPP

#include <iostream>
#include "State.cpp"
#include "Ability.cpp"

class Man {
protected:
    std::string name;
    State* state;
    Ability* abil;
public:
    Man(std::string name="Man1") {
        this->name = name;
    }
    ~Man() {}
};

#endif
```

Есть класс State в котором будет хп и урон манчика

```
#ifndef STATE_CPP
#define STATE_CPP

class State {
protected:
    int hp;
    int damage;
public:
    State(int hp = 100, int dp = 25) {
        this->hp = hp;
        this->damage = dp;
    }

    ~State() {}

    int getHp() {
        return hp;
    }

    int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

};

#endif
```

и есть класс Ability - в котором должен быть метод атаковать другого манчика

```
#ifndef ABILITY_CPP
#define ABILITY_CPP


class Ability {
public:
    // void fight(Man& man) {
    //     man->hp -= this->damage;
    // }

};

#endif
```

вся проблема вот в этой части

```
void fight(Man& man) {
     man->hp -= this->damage;  
 }
```

я не могу напрямую достучаться до класса Man.

Обязательно надо сохранить классы State и Ability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса `Man` нет переменной `hp`, она есть у класса `State`, агрегированного в `Man`. Есть несколько вариантов доступа.

**Вариант 1 (делегирование)**

```
class Man {
    public :
        void setHp(int hp) {
            state->hp = hp;
        }
}

void Ability::fight(Man& man) {
    man->setHp(man->getHp() - damage);  
}
```

**Вариант 2 (прямой доступ к агрегату)**

```
class State {
    public :
        void setHp(int _hp) {
            hp = _hp;
        }
}

class Man {
    public :
        inline State* state() {
            return state;
        }
}

void Ability::fight(Man& man) {
    man->state()->setHp(man->state()->getHp() - damage);  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно так что бы класс Ability остался?

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko Пардон... Область видимости при копипасте прохлопал. Поправил.

Comment: скорее всего я не правильно выразил то что хотел донести. У меня от класса Ability будет дальше наследоваться другие класс для разных типов юнитов(Man) так же само и State. Когда я в классе Ability в методе fight хочу достучаться до Man "void Ability::fight(Man& man)" то получаю еррор unknown type name 'Man'

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko На неправильно заданный вопрос можно правильно ответить только случайно. Исправляйте вопрос, чтобы он **в точности** соответствовал проблеме. Если есть наследование, то и напишите его в коде.